# Node.js q module - after then using function

Tags: node.js, rest, q

So I am using the q module in node.js to try and make a rest call and get data asynchronously, what I would like to know, is how I can use the then method to pass that data to a function.

For example, if I had a function called  getData() that returned defer.promise, and I set up a variable to get that promise like this -

```
var promise = getData();
```

I know I can use

```
promise.then(console.log, console.error);
```

and it will print out the data I retrieved from the rest call

however, how could I for example, pass that data to a function called sortData(data)?

```
promise.then(sortData(data), console.error);
```

doesnt work for example, does anyone know how to do this? or do I have to do the same thing I did before and keep doing asynchronous functions using defer? use .then.then.then? I am just not sure how to pass the data I got asynchronously into a function as the input for that function.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
promise.then(sortData, console.error);
```

`q`'s `then` accepts two callback functions as arguments -- a success callback and an error callback.

Comment: Thanks! so when I call that callback function, sortData, would you mind telling me how to access the data I got asynchronously? I did a rest GET request and got data parsed as a json, and did then.function(response) { defer.resolve(response)   , so wheni use the promise.then(sortData, console.error), how can I access that json inside sortData?

Comment: You'll get that data as your first argument to your `sortData` function.

Comment: Awesome thanks you have been a big help. If you dont mind me asking one more quick question, what if I wanted to accept other arguments to that function? like the function was-- sortData(data, dataType) ... and the first argument there is the data automatically being passed from the promise... how can I pass some variable to the second argument dataType?

Comment: `promise.then((data) => sortData(data, dataType), console.error);` or `promise.then(function(data) { return sortData(data, dataType); }, console.error);`